# php array_slice cant find array

Tags: php, slice

Im getting some data trough someone elses script that forms an array I want to slice because there is a lot of old data in there and I only need the latest newest data.

Im creating an array from xml like this:

```
    $result = (object)$SOAP->Export($token, $exportCmd, $admin);

    if($result->response->code != APIResponse::Success)
      die("Failed to Export");

    $exportedXML = $result->exportResult;

    $xml = trim(str_replace("Content-type: text/xml", " ", $exportedXML));

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    $json = json_encode($xml);

    $response = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

If I print the response I get something like this:

```
Array ( 
[R2420] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [F2400] => 00200002 [F2425] => 01 [F2426] => 050 ) 
[1] => Array ( [F2001] => text [F2400] => 00200002 [F2425] => 00 [F2426] => 060 ) 
[2] => Array ( [F2001] => text [F2400] => 00200008 [F2425] => 01 [F2426] => 080 ) 
[3] => Array ( [F2001] => text [F2400] => 00200008 [F2425] => 02 [F2426] => 080 ) 
[4] => Array ( [F2001] => text [F2400] => 00200026 [F2425] => 00 [F2426] => 150 ) 
[5] => Array ( [F2400] => 00200038 [F2425] => 01 [F2426] => 330 )
)
)
```

This one goes to 5, the actual one till about 2000. I want for example only the last 200. But when I use  `$output = array_slice($response, -200, 200);` It wont slice anything off, I think thats because its an array in an array, but how do I slice that?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a side-note: `APIResponse::Success` suggests you're using a class constant. Convention is to write constant names in UPPER-CASE, class names and statics are are Ucfirst

Answer (score 0):

You could just

```
$output = array_slice($response[0], -200, 200);
```

If you were sure that it was the first element in the array you wanted.

Just make sure to wrap it in a check that $response[0] exists.

```
$output = false;
if (!empty($response[0]))
    $output = array_slice($response[0], -200, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

" If length is given and is negative then the sequence will stop that many elements from the end of the array. If it is omitted, then the sequence will have everything from offset up until the end of the array. " - php.net

So what you want to do is simply:
`$output = array_slice($response, -200);`

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue: the array the OP wants to slice is inside the `$response` array. `array_slice($foo,-200,200);` is perfectly valid, though the third argument is a overkill

Comment: Is it? As I understood it, the OP wants to slice the outer array.

Comment: Just look at the example response in the OP's question, and the actual question: _"t wont slice anything off, I think thats because its an array in an array, but how do I slice that?"_ -> array in array is what he wants to slice

Answer (score 0):

Simple, slice the array you want sliced:

```
$output = array_slice($repsonse['R2420'],-200);
```

I'm assuming the key `R2420` is known to you. If not:

```
$output = array_slice(reset($response), -200);
```

You needn't use `reset`, of course: `array_pop`, `array_shift`, `end`... will all do, too. Whichever gets you the array you want to splice the quickest (and easiest).
If you want to splice all sub-arrays:

```
$output = array();
foreach($response as $part => $arr)
{
    $output[$part] = array_slice($arr, -200);
}
```

PS: if you want the last 200 indexes, you needn't specify the third parameter